# Detect audio from the user and converte to text to command AI bots in Unity

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a game where I want to command the AI using word i speak.
Say for example I can say go and AI bot goes to certain distance.

Question is I am finding asset and no provider is giving me grantee that it is possible ?

What are the difficulties for doing it?

I am programmer so if some one suggest the way to handle it I can do it.

Should I make mic listener on all the time and read audio and then pass audio to some external sdk which can convert my voice to text ?

these are the asset provider i have contacted.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/73036

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45168

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/47520

and few more !
If someone just explains the steps I need to follow then I can try it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using this external api for pretty much the same thing: https://api.ai/

It comes with a unity SDK that works quite well:
https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-unity-sample#apiai-unity-plugin

You have to connect a audio source to the sdk, and tell it to start listening. It will then convert your voice audio to text, and even detect pre-selected intentions from your voice audio / text.

You can find all steps on how to integrate the unity plugin in the api.ai Unity SDK documentation on github.

EDIT: It's free too btw :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recognize offline without sending data to the server, you need to try this plugin:

https://github.com/dimixar/unity3DPocketSphinx-android-lib

It uses open source speech recognition engine [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Okay let me try it .
i found something for windows too.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html

85% accuracy I got if head phone is close to mouth.